# Get updates to fb user feed by others

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I need to know when another user has commented/liked a post by one of my users or if they have tagged/mentioned one of my users so that I can act on these events.

I have fb realtime setup but that only tells me that something has changed.   I know I can query using FQL but I don't see how I can say "after a certain timestamp".   Same issue with using graph API to get a feed.  I just get the entire feed.

Is there a way to just get changes from a certain time or after a certain other event whose id I could store?   Or can people recommend best practices for accomplishing this?

Comment: This seems very sticky because if you use graph api to get feed, likes don't appear to have creation dates.   So does that imply I'd have to cache all the likes for every post, then "diff" those against updated versions to see if there are additional likes and by who so I can notify my users?  If so, yuck.